# Rails undo at database level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I'd line to create some kind of undo in my rails app, that's based on an sqlite3 database.
For now, a database wide undo would suffice, I mean an undo that can return back in time through states of the whole database, not single tables (for avoiding problems with references etc..)

I found vestal_versions, but it's table level and a bit too complicated for what I need.. don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a full-stack solution to this problem, but check out [ActiveLog](http://github.com/parolkar/active_log) and [Memento](http://github.com/yolk/memento).

Don't forget to share you solution here! :-)